# Cannot add object to NS array

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of restaurants defined in the header file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *resPool; //pool of restaurants
```

Now I am trying to add a restaurant object to this array by doing the following in the .m file:

```
id restaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithResName:resName]
[self.resPool addObject:restaurant];// add the restaurant to the res pool array
```

The resName NSArray remains empty when I run this code. I am not sure what I'm doing wring. I am just trying to pick up objective C. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying `resPool = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];` anywhere. Allocate memory to the `resPool` and then do operations on them. Generally, memory allocation is done in your initializer. Do this any of your class's `init` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not `instantiated` the array, thus you can't add an object to it.

Try to add this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)resPool {
    if (!_resPool) _resPool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _resPool;
}
```

It's called lazy instansiation in Objective-C, and it's pretty common